# How to convert/get name of variable or maybe convert part of code into string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Help please to get name of variable from this self variable.

```
let variable = 'blablabla'
magic... and i have: variable = 'variable'
```

Comment: It's not remotely clear what you're trying to ask here. Can you provide more details? A clearer idea of the end result you want?

Comment: It sounds like you want to print out the name of the `variable` but isn't clear because you have named your `variable` "variable.". Can you rename your `variable` in your example so that the question is less confusing?

Comment: It might also be helpful to let us know WHY you want to do this. There may be a better way to accomplish your goals.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with plain variables as far as I can tell.
That said, it's easy to get the keys from an object.

Example:

```
let variable = {
  prop1: 'value'
};

console.log(Object.keys(variable)); // <= will print ['prop1']
```